# Entity Framework 6.0 - Oracle 12c - ERROR Unsupported Column Type(XMLType)

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6, code-first, oracle12c, xmltype

I'm getting **Unsupported Column Type** error while fetching data from entity from **Oracle 12c, in Entity Framework 6.0**. The query is:

```
var caseActivityData = (from activity in this.Context.CaseActivityData
                                where activity.CaseId == caseId
                                   && activity.ActivityId == activityId
                                   && activity.ActivityTypeId == activityTypeId
                                select activity).ToList();
```

We are assuming the issue is with XMLType column - the field "public string CaseActivityDataValues { get; set; }" is XMLType in database.

The ENTITY is:

```
[Table("CASE_ACTIVITY_DATA")]
public class CaseActivityData
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ACTIVITY_ID")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ActivityId { get; set; }

    [Column("CASE_ID")]
    public int CaseId { get; set; }

    [Column("CASE_ACTIVITY_DATA_TYPE_ID")]
    public int ActivityTypeId { get; set; }

    [Column("WHO_UPDATED")]
    public string WhoUpdated { get; set; }

    [Column("CASE_DATA_VALUES")]
    public string CaseActivityDataValues { get; set; }

    [Column("DATE_UPDATED")]
    public DateTime? DateUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

The context mapping is:

```
public virtual DbSet<CaseActivityData> CaseActivityData { get; set; }
```

Please suggest.